# subtracting negative numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, subtraction, negative-number

I know in order to turn a number into a negative in assembly, I need to turn it into two's complement by xor'ing it then adding one.

I've done this, but my output is still incorrect, can someone please explain to me where I have made a mistake?

The object is to subtract -val1 - val2 - val3

Here is the bulk of my code

`.data
val1     dword  10000h
val2     dword  40000h
val3     dword  20000h
finalVal dword  ?`

.code
main PROC

```
mov eax,val1            ; start with 10000h
xor eax,val1            ; xor eax to make it almost negative
add eax,1h              ; now add one to make it negative
sub eax,val2            ; subtract 40000h
sub eax,val3            ; subtract 20000h
mov finalVal,eax        ; store the result (30000h)
call    DumpRegs        ; display the registers

exit
```

https://ideone.com/hulsdU

The final result should be EAX=FFF90000
but currently my output is EAX=FFFA0001

note that I am using 32 bit numbers, and running this on an x86 processor.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
mov eax,val1
xor eax,val1
  ; (a XOR a) is always 0. Using the line above you XOR
  ; val1 with val1 so EAX will always be 0 here!
add eax,1h
  ; (Ok. EAX will be 1 here...)
sub eax,val2
  ...
```

If you want to negate a number you can use the "NEG" instruction:

```
neg eax
```

If you want to do this using the ones complement you use the "NOT" instruction:

```
not eax
add eax, 1h
```

Or:

```
not eax
inc eax
```